# YUI 2.0 calendar - how to get current calendar page

Tags: javascript, yui

I'm looking for a way to get the current pagedate. I know how to get the original config or even how to subscribe to changePageEvent and get it while scrolling, but neither covers a case when someone opens the calendar scrolls through few months and then closes and re-opens, I need the pagedate for that page. There has to be a property that records that, but can't find in the API.

Comment: Why doesn't changePageEvent work for you? It gives you the date after changing pages.  Are you using the same calendar instance or are you popping up a new calendar each time?

Comment: It doesn't fire when you scroll few months, close the calendar and then re-open. The calendar re-opens to the last month you scrolled to, but changePageEvent doesn't fire.

Comment: The event fires when changing months on this example: [Calendar Control: Handling Calendar Events](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/events_log.html) so my initial take is that you're not doing it right. Perhaps I'm unclear on your problem - post some source code please.

Comment: Yes, but this is a pop-up calendar which is inside a dialog and can be closed (hidden). So when it's reopen (shown) no changePage event occurs. I'll probably write last known pagadate to a global variable and read it on reopen, but I was hoping there is a pagedate property that stores current page month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a popup calendar that remains on the last calendar page viewed, even if a date isn't selected.  Browse to a month and close the calendar using the "x" in the corner.  When you click the button to display the calendar again you'll find it's on the same page you last navigated to:

[Calendar Control: Popup Calendar - Basic](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/calendar/popup.html)

I don't see any code in the example source code that sets the date, so in the absence of your source code I'll have to guess that you're instantiating a new calendar each time you show it.

To get the month/year displayed use the [pagedate property](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Calendar.html#config_pagedate).

Comment: Thanks Paul. My calendar works the same way and when closed and reopened stays on the month (same instance) I closed it on. All great! All I want is to GET the pagedate that the calendar reopened to. I'm working on a pretty complex set of calendars and the code is lenghty. This part I want to ultimately use to hide navigation icons to prevent scrolling beyond certain date range.

Comment: I understand now and have added to my answer.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you do it with calendar_obj.cfg.getProperty('pagedate') and not calendar_obj._parsePageDate() as I was doing.